# PHP json_encode encode only a key

Tags: php, json

As an API response to a payment gateway I receive an object, I would like it to become json so I used *json_encode*, but I only get the first key.

Comment: Provide your Api response in your question itself.

Comment: You must be giving the wrong argument to `json_encode()`.

Comment: @Amanjaura How? I use APIs with a library, the library give a object, I want convert this into json string, but I only get the first key.

Comment: Then add that object response that you are getting back from the library in the question itself. Then we will see where we can go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*json_encode* convert only the first key cause array is too large

Answer (score 0):

json_encode convert array to json
json_decode convert json to array

API’s by default must give you a json and you must decode json data to array if you are going to use it on back-end.

Show some code, so we can help you

Comment: *Show some code, so we can help you* <- Should be a comment and not an answer

Comment: No... APIs isn't with http, is a library, I get a object but i want convert into json script, I use json_encode but i get a json string with only a key.